# Accept user input

Tags: io, user-input, malbolge

I am currently writing a text-adventure type game in Malbolge.

Can anyone tell me how to accept a user input in Malbolge?  I am able to output text to the screen, however, I can't seem to figure out how to accept input.

Comment: Two choices: not a real question, or user is insane. Which is correct?

Comment: Heh. I vote for insane.

Comment: Who isn't stumped when it comes to Malbolge?

Comment: "The day that someone writes, in Malbolge, a program that simply copies its input to it's output, is the day my hair spontaneously turns green. It's the day that elephants are purple and camels fly, and a cow can fit through a needle's eye. " From the docs

Comment: 'I suspect the best way to do arithmetic is by table lookup.' is about the greatest statement ever.

Comment: ('&%:9]!~}|z2Vxwv-,POqponl$Hjig%eB@@>}=<M:9wv6WsU2T|nm-,jcL(I&%$#"
`CB]V?Tx<uVtT`Rpo3NlF.Jh++FdbCBA@?]!~|4XzyTT43Qsqq(Lnmkj"Fhg${z@>

Comment: I nominate this for Question of the Century.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
GHJUYGHJKLKUJHM;&MJ:6AG9F5D8V)A8%]>75Q;6EE85U955%-245!/3DU,2TI)
M2$=&141#0D% /SX]/#LZ.3@W-C4T,S(Q,"\N+2PK*BDH)R8E)",B(7Y]?'MZ
M>7AW=G5T<W)Q<&]N;6QK:FEH9V9E9&-B86!?7EU<6UI96%=655134E%03TY-
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: Only in a cruel and hopeless world like ours can such a thing as Malbolge be created.

Comment: Hmm, the markdown editor is having some trouble highlighting Malboge syntax.  I'll file a bug report.

Comment: @BjornTipling I think you mean Java.