# How can I read and write a file in Malbolge?

Tags: file-io, malbolge

I'm trying to write a social networking site in Malbolge with CGI. I need to store data in a database. How can I read and write files in Malbolge?

Comment: the question here is. Why would you make a social network in malbolge?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing this with another programming language?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is this the same Malbolge which is deliberately so difficult to write programs in that it took two years for the first program to be discovered (by a brute force search of the program space)? And which it then took cryptanalysis to find out how to write programs *on purpose*?

If so, the answer is that you can't --- it has no I/O capability other than stdin and stdout. Although I suppose you could connect it via a pty to a command line of some description.

Comment: This question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859314/stumped-in-malbolge Otherwise, good luck, and I'm sure that if you do succeed then some kind of major award will be due to you once you get out of the asylum...

Comment: Or maybe the goal of the OP was to build a social network for the inhabitants of Malbolge of Dante's Inferno ... who knows ...